# The Expo SDK requires Expo to run. Reac Native Builded Apk

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have created the app with Expo.

Everything is fine I can run the app on ios and android emulator.

When I use `cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease` command to have an apk file.

I have a successful result.
But When I install that apk on any android device It crashes immidiately after running the app

I managed to get a stack trace from the device and here is what it says.

> The Expo SDK requires Expo to run. It appears the native Expo modules are unavailable and this code is not running on Expo. Visit https://docs.expo.io to learn more about developing an Expo project., stack:

Version Information

```js
"@expo/vector-icons": "^10.0.6",
"@react-native-community/netinfo": "^4.6.0",
"expo": "^35.0.0",
"expo-barcode-scanner": "^7.0.0",
"expo-font": "^7.0.0",
"expo-image-manipulator": "^7.0.0",
"expo-image-picker": "^7.0.0",
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-dom": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "0.59.10",
"react-native-custom-qr-codes-expo": "^2.2.0",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.3.0",
"react-native-image-placeholder": "^1.0.14",
```

As I result I cant publish my app to playstore.

Any help or suggestion will be appriciated.

Comment: you probably need to use expo to upload and distribute your app. have you tried [this](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v35.0.0/distribution/uploading-apps/)?

Comment: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/building-standalone-apps/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See, the problem is you chose expo and now you are generating the APK via the normal bare react native project, that is without using expo. 
The command

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

is used to generate apk for bare react native app.  So that's why its asking that Expo SDK requires expo to run. And its throwing the error , coz APK wasnt build with the expo wrapper on top of it.

For expo , you need to use `expo build:android or expo build:ios`  , you can refer the docs here [Expo apk link](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/building-standalone-apps/). After that i hope it will solve the error.

Hope it helps.Feel free to ask any doubts.